# Getting data from particular year in date field

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose i am having data as shown below

```
ACT_NO     DATE1          AMOUNT
12111201   2/1/2009     66600.00
12111201   8/31/2009    66600.00
12111201   7/29/2008   133200.00
12111201   5/19/2009    66600.00
```

I need to get the sum of amount for particular year 2009 ie from 1/31/2009 to 31/12/2009.
How I will get as per year? The date1 field is in date format in oracle. I am using pl sql developer

Answer (score 1):

As long as date1 has no time component you could use:

```
where date1 between date '2009-01-01' and '2009-12-31'
```

That can use an index on date1.  Another solution (that could not use a simple index on date1) is:

```
where trunc(date1,'YYYY') = date '2009-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

This query sums the AMT column for a given year.  The inclusion of the YEAR in the result is optional; if you don't want it you won't need the GROUP BY clause either.

```
select to_char(date1, 'YYYY') as year
       , sum(amount) as year_total
from your_table
where date1 between to_date('01-JAN-2009', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                and to_date('31-DEC-2009 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
group by to_char(date1, 'YYYY')    
/
```

The query presumes that DATE1 has a DATE datatype and includes a time element (hence the additional formatting in the AND arm of the BETWEEN clause).  If DATE1 is ill-mannered enough to be a string, the easiest kludge is just to case it to a date first.

Comment: TRUNC(date1,'YY') is an alternative to TO_CHAR

Answer (score 0):

```
with sampleData as(
select 12111201   ACT_NO, to_date('2/1/2009' ,'mm/dd/rrrr') DATE1 ,    66600.00 AMOUNT from dual union all 
select 12111201   ACT_NO, to_date('8/31/2009','mm/dd/rrrr') DATE1 ,    66600.00 AMOUNT from dual union all 
select 12111201   ACT_NO, to_date('7/29/2008','mm/dd/rrrr') DATE1 ,   133200.00 AMOUNT from dual union all 
select 12111201   ACT_NO, to_date('5/19/2009','mm/dd/rrrr') DATE1 ,    66600.00 AMOUNT from dual 
)

select extract(year from date1) date1_year 
       ,sum(amount) amount_summed
       ,count(distinct ACT_NO) distinctAccounts
       , count(*) total_occurrences
  from sampleData
```

/*where date1 between to_date('01-JAN-2009', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                and to_date('31-DEC-2009 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')*/ --from @APC's answer

```
group by extract(year from date1)
/

DATE1_YEAR             AMOUNT_SUMMED          DISTINCTACCOUNTS       TOTAL_OCCURRENCES      
---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- 
2008                   133200                 1                      1                      
2009                   199800                 1                      3
```

You may also use [extract(year from dateField)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm)

Although unless you want to create an index on the function, utilizing @APC's or @Tony Andrews' is the way to go for filtering on the year.